# What message is generated by the chrome "permissions" property in an extension manifest?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions

Given a manifest containing the following "permissions" array, what message can a user expect to see when installing an extension with this permission in Chrome?

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "http://www.google.com/"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit `chrome://extensions`, search for your extension and click on "Details" ("Permissions" in Chrome 40 and earlier). That will display a screen with the [permission warnings](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings) that you'd see if the user installs the extension.

You can also use the [`chrome.management.getPermissionWarningsByManifest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-getPermissionWarningsByManifest) method to get a list of permission warnings for a given string that contains the contents of the manifest file.

[image]

Comment: Do you know what the permission warning "Read and modify all your data on your computer and the websites you visit" actually entails? Can a plugin get all your banking data on the bank of america site, then send it to other domain?

Comment: @trusktr An extension can already do what you stated with a lighter permission which "only" triggers the "Read and modify your data on www.bankofamerica.com" warning. The warning that you mentioned is triggered when a (deprecated and soon to be dropped) [NPAPI plugin](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi) is used in a Chrome extension. NPAPI plugins are unsandboxed, and can bypass any security restrictions that Chrome enforces for extensions and run any code with your system user's permissions, hence they have the potention to "read and modify all your data on your **computer**".

Comment: Thanks rob, sorry, i pasted the wrong permission, i meant just the permission that can read and modify data on any website you visit (no plugin). Can that chrome extension send banking data to another domain?

Comment: @trusktr Yes, of course. Have you read the https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings documentation that I linked in my answer?

Comment: I scrolled down to the nice table, then I read every word in the section It doesn't say data can be transmitted to another domain, or even just transmitted. Seems like a poor design on Google's behalf. Do you see it there?

Comment: @trusktr Why should the documentation explictly mention that? If an extension can access data on any domain, then they can do whatever they want with it, including sending the data to an attacker-controlled website. "Transmitting" data is trivial, e.g. by serializing the data and appending it to an URL, and then try to request that URL, e.g. opening the URL in a new tab, loading the URL as an image, sending a direct request to the website (an extension does not need explicit permission if the website has enabled [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)).

Comment: Accessing data in any domain doesn't automatically imply sending it somewhere other than the domain the data is accessed from. It should say so.